# HighChart Tooltip addition text and value

Tags: highcharts

I have created a column chart using Highchart, and would like to add additional text and value to the tooltip, without using the point.y or point.x and i am not trying to work out the sum/avg, its a self-generated value and text.

Any suggestion please.[Please see highlighted example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beUJW.png)

Comment: Can you put the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Hi Sadaf, please see link https://jsfiddle.net/andrew2343e/Ld7648xn/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare tooltip options with formatter function:

```
options: {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>' 
              + '<br/>'  + 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.extra + '</b>';
        },
    }
}
```

And define series data like below:

```
data:[
   {
      y: 49.9, 
      extra: 49.9
   },
   {
      y: 71.5,
      extra: 71.5
   },
   ...
],
```

---

[See jsfiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sadafniknaam/b1o4rjwL/4/)
[image: Result]